# Can't Open .rtf When made in terminal 2013 MacBook Air Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: macos, terminal.app, rtf

Whenever I make a `.rtf` in the terminal app, with the touch command:

`touch FileName.rtf`

I am only able to open the file with terminal and I am unable to open the file with any other program i.e. text edit, Microsoft word, etc. facing this message:

[image: Error message image]

This is really bugging me. If I do the same process with a `.txt` file I can open the file with any editor.

Any info is appreciated; Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Text editor. Create an "empty" rtf file - no text and save it. Then right-click the file in Finder, select "info" or press CMD-I. No you see the file is about 202 bytes in size. The file you created is 0 bytes. Those 202 bytes seem like nothing, but they hold the basic structure of an rtf-file.